# Removing no data area (sea) from raster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, srtm

I have some difficulties removing the no data part from a GeoTIFF SRTM. I need to remove all sea parts. I'm new in ArcGIS.

[image]

[image]

This is the result i wanted

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to remove it from view i.e. with symbology or are you doing some analysis in which the NoData boundary has some effect on the output and you want to eliminate it from the analysis.

Comment: Since this region is going to be used for graphical rappresentation i guess i have to remove it just from the view right ??

Comment: do you have a value when you click with the identify tool ? Maybe it is set to zero or -1 (and only the white line along the coast is NoData)

Comment: Value at the left of the boundary (sea area) is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to Symbology under Layer Properties of your image, there is an option to Display Background Values. You can choose 'No Color' and that should remove the black sea part.

Comment: Actually i did try that option before  before, it is set as  Colour is Null. Still it is appearing. I tried to define the no data value at the raster dataset properties in arc catalog but the result is the same.

Comment: Weird I feel like this should work maybe post a screen shot of the symbology properties box in the question so we can check it out.

Comment: Try the Background Value field

Comment: Thank you very much it did work i just checked Display Background value  0 and it dissapeared.

Answer (score 1):

Most times I use a boundary polygon to clip the raster. You can find the tool under Raster Processing.

Comment: I will have to try this way too since i have to hillshade the raster and the no data area appears.